# docker run mysql images but it terminate automaticly

Tags: mysql, docker

I'm just using docker for first time and I copy it on the internet
This is my file

Dockerfile

```
FROM mysql:oracle
COPY dbscript.sql  /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

and I build it with this command

```
docker build -t mysqllab
```

after built I run it

```
docker run -d --name mysqllabtest -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD='abc123' mysqllab
```

it's run and get the message of container id, so I run

```
docker ps
```

to see what my container is running but it's don't have this container, I try it again with fast docker ps so I see it run for 4 seconds and terminate
What Can I do with this?

Comment: Check the logs with `docker logs mysqllabtest` after it has exited.

Comment: thanks :D, it's about my mysql script it's have some error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just use

```
docker logs mysqllabtest
```

for check something wrong it about MySQL script so after I edited it It's works! thanks @Hans Kilian for tell me this command